# Soma ignorando número apagado

Tags: jquery

Em meu sistema, gero dinamicamente colunas com datas a base de um parâmetro recebido, construindo uma tabela onde em X tenho produtos e Y tenho a quantidade que vem em cada embalagem, relação de datas no `th` com inputs para digitar quantos o cliente gostaria de receber em cada data, e o total.

O problema é que quando digito a quantidade, ela acumula, ignora se caso eu apagar o valor de um input e digitar outro, ou seja, se eu tinha os valores 2, 3 e 5 em cada input, totalizando 10, se eu apagar o valor 3 e escrever 1 ele totaliza 11.

Meu script abaixo:

```
    var Meses = [];
    var IDs = [];
    IDs = pID.split(",");
    var IDAtual = 0;

    Meses.push(mesInicial + "/" + Ano);
    while (CountMes < 5 && Diferenca > CountMes) {
        CountMes++;
        mesInicial++;
        if (mesInicial > 12) {
            mesInicial = mesInicial - 12;
            if (Ano < Ano + 1) {
                Ano++;
            }
        }
        Meses.push(mesInicial + "/" + Ano);
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = Meses.length; i < l; i++) {
        $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:first').each(function () {
            $(this).append("<th class='text-center'>" + Meses[i] + "</th>");
        });

        if ((l - 1) == i) {
            IDAtual = 0;
        }

        $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
            $(this).append("<td ><input type='number' class='qtdItem' data-id='" + IDs[IDAtual] + "' /></td>");
            IDAtual++;
        });
    }

    $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:first').each(function () {
        $(this).append("<th class='text-center'>Total</th>");
    });
    $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
        $(this).append("<td><input type='number' class='totalQTD'  disabled='disabled' value='0' /></td>");
    });
```

Abaixo está a parte mais importante, onde faço a soma

```
        var sum = 0;
    $('input').on("keyup", function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = IDs.length; i < l; i++) {
            if ($(this).attr('data-id') == IDs[i]) {
                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
                }
                var Total = $(this).parent().parent().find('.totalQTD').val(sum);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sua variável `sum` nunca é resetada para zero quando você apaga todo o conteúdo do input. Você poderia colocar esta var sum = 0 dentro do `$('input').on("keyup", function () {` e acredito que já deva resolver o seu problema, porém existe formas mais eficientes de fazer o mesmo.

Comment: @PedroHenrique Eu até tentei, mas como tenho inputs x,y. Quando ativo a função via input X e coloco valor 1, minha sum fica 1. Porém se chamar a função por meio do input Y após ter definido valor 1, ele vai ignorar o 1, setar novamente pra 0 e aplicar o valor apenas do input Y

Comment: Entendo, o que você pode fazer é o seguinte, criar uma função que tem como único objetivo, percorrer por todos os inputs e calcular o valor de cada um, considerando se é zero. Mas sempre calcular todos os inputs. E dentro do seu  `$('input').on("keyup", function () {` você apenas faz a chamada desta função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte forma

```
var CountMes = 0;

function DataTabela(mesInicial, Diferenca, Ano, pID, pValor) {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("compromissoInserir2") > -1) {

    var Meses = [];
    var IDAtual = 0;

    Meses.push(mesInicial + "/" + Ano);
    while (CountMes < 5 && Diferenca > CountMes) {
        CountMes++;
        mesInicial++;
        if (mesInicial > 12) {
            mesInicial = mesInicial - 12;
            if (Ano < Ano + 1) {
                Ano++;
            }
        }
        Meses.push(mesInicial + "/" + Ano);
    }

    for (var i = 0, l = Meses.length; i < l; i++) {
        $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:first').each(function () {
            $(this).append("<th class='text-center'>" + Meses[i] + "</th>");
        });

        if ((l - 1) == i) {
            IDAtual = 0;
        }

        $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
            $(this).append("<td ><input type='number' class='p" + pID[IDAtual] + "'   data-id='" + pID[IDAtual] + "' data-preco='" + pValor[IDAtual] + "' /></td>");
            IDAtual++;
        });
    }

    $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:first').each(function () {
        $(this).append("<th class='text-center'>Total</th>");
    });
    $('#NovoCompromisso').find('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
        $(this).append("<td><input type='number' class='totalQTD'  disabled='disabled' value='0' /></td>");
    });

    $('input').on("keyup", function () {
        for (var i = 0, l = pID.length; i < l; i++) {
                sumInputValuesByClass("p" + pID[i]);
        }
    });

   }
}

function sumInputValuesByClass(c) {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.' + c).each(function () {
        sum += +$(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.totalQTD').val((sum));
    });
}
```

Comment: Considera marcar a tua resposta como aceite para o "sistema" parar de fazer _bump_ enviando a mesma para a fila de perguntas ativas quando este assunto já não é propriamente ativo! :)

Comment: Aproveita também e explica de que forma resolveste o problema para que futuros leitores a passar pelo mesmo entendam a solução!